# Find a pattern in string and replace the detected string slightly modified

Tags: r, regex

So I am dealing with some data cleaning in R and I am stuck with the following problem.

I want to detect the following pattern

> abc.xyz

and to replace it with

> abc. xyz

What I have tried is doing with gsub the following way:

```
gsub("\\w+\\.\\w+", "\\w+\\. \\w+", character_vector, perl = TRUE)
```

However, what I get as an output is the detected characters are replaced with the literal "w+. w+".

I have removed urls and emails beforehand so these should not be a problem. The problem is coming from the fact when using **unnest_sentences**, the function cannot separate sentences when the above pattern is true.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use capturing groups with backreferences in the replacement pattern (and in this case, a default TRE regex engine can cope with the task):

```
gsub("(\\w+\\.)(\\w+)", "\\1 \\2", character_vector)
```

Here, `(\w+\.)(\w+)` captures 1+ word chars and a dot into Group 1 (`\1`) and then 1+ word chars are captured into Group 2 (`\2`).

Alternatively, you may use lookarounds (then, you will need a PCRE engine enabled with the `perl=TRUE` argument):

```
gsub("\\w+\\.\\K(?=\\w)", " ", character_vector, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/y3aTyA).

Here, `\w+\.` matches 1+ word chars and a dot, but `\K` omits that text and `(?=\w)` just makes sure the next char is a word char. So, the replacement pattern is a mere space here.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!